# Laravel File manager - Create Folder or File events

Tags: laravel, file-manager, unisharp-file-manager

I have used **Unisharp/Laravel-filemanager** for my File Manager system. I need an **event** for calling a function when a user creates a folder. How can I do it?

I have tried to find some information about it on their website [Laravel File manager events](https://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager/events) but I can't find anything that helps me. do you have any solution or suggestion for me?

Comment: kindly add more details

Comment: you should create a custom event, check my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the [Unisharp/Laravel-filemanager](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager) package, there is no relevant event, i.e. `FolderCreated`, here is [list of all events that package works with](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager/tree/master/src/Events) so you have to define a custom event using following steps:

**Step 1:** Create your custom event,

```
php artisan make:event FolderCreatedByUser
```

**Step 2:**

Define references to user and folder inside event class:

```
class FolderCreatedByUser
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $folder;
    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user, $folder)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->folder= $folder;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('user_folders');
    }
}
```

**Step 3:**

Add a listener for `FolderCreatedByUser` event:

```
php artisan make:listener UserFolderCreationListener

<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\FolderCreatedByUser;

class UserFolderCreationListener
{
    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param object $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(FolderCreatedByUser $event)
    {
        $user = $event->user;
        $folder = $event->folder;
        // call your function here!
    }
}
```

**Step 4:**
Open `app/Providers/EventServiceProvider` and register the listener for the event:

```
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [

        FolderCreatedByUser::class => [
            UserFolderCreationListener::class
        ],
        .
        .
        .
```

**Final Step**

When user creates a new folder, dispatch an event:

```
FolderCreatedByUser::dispatch(auth()->user(), $folder);
```